# Powershell script - Remove-AppxPackage

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm trying to build a powershell script to do 4 things:

1. Create a list with `Get-AppxPackage` and `Output-File` - works
2. Erase with `Remove-AppxPackage` - doesn't work
3. Display a list on the terminal - works
4. Quit the script - works

How do I put the second option running without problems?

Here's the code for the second option:

```
function Erase {
    ([string] $app) = Read-Host -Prompt "Insert the AppxPackage name."
    cls
    Write-Host $app
    $appchoice = Read-Host -Prompt "Is this the correct name? Answer Y or N."
    cls
    If (($appchoice -eq 'Y') -or ($appchoice -eq 'y')) {
        Get-AppxPackage "'$app'" | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers "'$app'"
        Write-Host "The package $app was erased."
        Read-Host -Prompt "Press enter to continue."
        Menu
    } Else {
        Write-Host "Somehow we messed things up. Let's start again!"
        Read-Host -Prompt "Press enter to continue."
        Menu
    }
}
```

The error is the image attached to this question. It doesn't even prompts the user for the name...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **1st** `Get-AppxPackage "'$app'"`  always returns `$null`. Use `"$app"` without inner apostrophes. **2nd** Using `Remove-AppxPackage`: specify package object either  from pipeline or as parameter `-Package "$app"` - not both.

Comment: `Erase` is an alias to `Remove-Item` in PowerShell. Choose a better name for your function like `Remove-App` or something. P.S. Read-Host always returns strings so instead of `([string] $app) = ...` do `$app = Read-Host ...`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply.
Now i can proceed but its causing a different error!